# First order ODE with Dirac delta funtcion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I am looking for a direct method to solve this first order ODE with Dirac delta funtcion

$$\frac{dU(t)}{dt}+k^2U(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\delta(t)$$

with the initial condition $U(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

The solution to this problem is $$U(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-k^2t}$$

My try

The integrating factor for this ode is
$$I=e^{\int k^2 dt }=e^{ k^2 t  }$$

then multiplying both sides of the differential equation by  $\,\,e^{ k^2 t  }$, we get

$$\frac{d }{d t}\left(e^{ k^2 t  } U(t)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ k^2 t  } \delta(t)$$
Integrating both sides, we have

$$e^{ k^2 t  } U(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int{e^{ k^2 t  } \delta(t)}dt+C$$

From here on, I am lost. Any suggestions?

**Back ground of this problem**

The above ode we got after applying Fourier transform to the following PDE
$$u_{t}=u_{xx}+\delta{(x)}\delta{(t)}$$
with $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$.

Comment: No, a solution is $U(t) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-k^2t} 1_{t > 0}$ (and $C e^{-k^2 t}$ are the solution to the homogeneous equation). Can you show us the steps for checking it is a solution ?

Comment: And $U(0) = 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is not correct (there is no solution that is continuous at $t= 0$)

Comment: @Ian or how to confuse the OP...

Comment: Anyway, you can dodge this difficulty by thinking physically a little bit: at the very beginning you have a unit mass at $x=0$, then you immediately add another unit mass at $x=0$ at the very beginning of the problem. Thus it is equivalent to solve $u_t=u_{xx},u(x,0)=2\delta(x)$.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on! If I am missing something in the question or in the solution then please let me know?

Comment: @MMM What is your definition of the Fourier transform?

Comment: @Ian $U(k,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,t)e^{-ikx}dx$

Comment: Sorry about my first comment, I made a sloppy error. Your conversion of the problem is OK. But now you can solve it the way that I mentioned in my second (now first) comment.

Comment: @Ian Please check my pseudo-answer.

Comment: I wonder if you have a redundant initial condition? What is normally seen is the following: $U’+k^2U=\delta(t)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and $U(0)=0$. This system is equivalent to the following: $U’+k^2U=0, t>0$ and $U(0)=1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. So I guess your ODE should be instead: $U’+k^2U=\delta(t)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and $U(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe an answer to my question but needs your conformation/validation.

Continuing from where I left
$$e^{ k^2 t  } U(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int{e^{ k^2 t  } \delta(t)}dt+C$$
$$\Rightarrow U(t)=\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int{e^{ k^2 t  } \delta(t)}dt+C\bigg]e^{ -k^2 t  }$$
Now recalling some properties of the Dirac delta function

1. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta(t)dt=f(0)$$
2. $$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\delta(t)dt=
   \begin{cases}
   f(0) & \text{if } a<t<b\\
   0 & \text{if } x=0
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Now since we are dealing with an IVP, where $t\geq0$, then adopting the above properties "we can have"
   $$\int{e^{ k^2 t  } \delta(t)}dt=e^{0}=1,$$

which gives 
$$U(t)=\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+C\bigg]e^{ -k^2 t  }$$
Finally utilizing the initial condition $U(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, gives $C=0$, and hence
$$U(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ -k^2 t  }$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It can't be correct for all times because there must be a jump at $t=0$. The usual way that one would interpret the solution to this ODE would be the result given by the Laplace transform, namely $(s+k^2)U(s)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ and so $U(s)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}(s+k^2)}$. Thus going forward in time starting from $t=0$, you have $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-k^2 t}$. Going backward in time you instead have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-k^2 t}$ (not that it makes any sense to send your original PDE back in time).

Comment: @Ian When I solve the ODE in Maple, it gives the solution $U(t)=\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}H(t)+C\bigg]e^{-k^2t}$.

Comment: Which is what I wrote, with $C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$.

Comment: @Ian  It seems that $\int{e^{ k^2 t  } \delta(t)}dt=H(t)$ but how ? If so, then how can we apply the initial condition to the Maple solution? I am thinking that $H(0)=1$ by definition then $C=0$ not the one you wrote.

Comment: $H (0) $ is not really defined. All you can really explain are the left and right limits. My interpretation of the problem is that your left limit should be $1/\sqrt {2 \pi} $ and your right limit should be $2/\sqrt {2\pi} $.

Comment: There is no initial condition for $U(0)$. What you have instead is that the system gets "switched on" at $t=0$, meaning that $U(t)=0$ for $t<0$. Then indeed for the constant $C=0$ is needed to have the "switched off" condition for $t<0$. In the end that gets you here $U(0^-)=0$ and $U(0^+)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.